# How to query sys tables using LINQ-to-SQL?

Tags: sql-server, linq-to-sql, linqpad

I am using LINQPad and I want to get the list of instance pipe names from the sys.dm_os_child_instances table.  How is that expressed in LINQ-to-SQL?

This doesn't work:

```
from n in sys.dm_os_child_instances
select n
```

I don't think it matters, but I am using SQL Server Express 2008.

Also, yes, I know I can run raw SQL from LINQPad.

Comment: Then **use** that raw SQL....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

LINQPad allows this query if you tick the 'Include System Views and SPs' checkbox in connection properties.

A couple of other points:

- If you have capitalization enabled, it's sys.Dm_os_child_instances rather than sys.dm_os_child_instances
- The query "from n in sys.Dm_os_child_instances select n" is valid but frivilous: you can just go "sys.Dm_os_child_instances"

Comment: +1 for the second point.  I see developers quite frequently doing that needlessly.